# HTTPS & Security

Tags: php, security, https

When a user logs in on my website, their data is passed through a seperate page, i.e. They log in on the login.php page, but the data is retrieved/stored/verified etc. on login.inc.php. So the user never sees this page, they are transferred straight to their profile page afterwards.

1. Should the login.php use HTTPS or the `login.inc.php` page? If so why, if not why not?
2. All data is sent through POST from the form, I use `$mysqli->real_escape_string`, prepared statements and hash the passwords using `hash_hmac`. Are these steps necessary if I am using HTTPS?
3. If not, what other security features should I implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You must only use HTTPS for those pages which the client interacts with (i.e. `login.php`) because `login.inc.php` gets included in the page by the server.
2. These steps don't relate to the usage of HTTPS, and are merely for internal script security (i.e. to prevent SQL injection, etc.).
3. As long as you use HTTPS for server-client interactions (provided all the external files like javascript and images in that page are also loaded via SSL), there shouldn't be any worries about the security of your connection.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just the answers I was looking for. :-)